# XSLT 2.0. Loop inside a Function

Tags: xslt-2.0

Hitting my wall here...

I've got the following data where a Primary Employee may have multiple dependents.  I need to create a function that will match the Employee's SSN (ab:SSN) against the Dependent_SSN and determine if one of them is a 'Spouse'.  If so, then we'll return the Dependent_SSN of the 'Spouse'. 
If not, we'll move on and return the next non-'Spouse' Dependent_SSN.

I'm trying to create a function as I think I'll need this more than once.  The code snippet resides inside of an existing template that is doing other looping functionality.

I've tried this but Oxygen returns an error:

```
<xsl:function name="ab:PQB">
    <xsl:param name="EE_SSN">
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:for-each select="/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]ab:dependents/ab:Dependent_SSN">

    </xsl:for-each>
```

The Error returned is :

"Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5
Severity: fatal
Description: Unexpected token name "wd:dependents" beyond end of expression"

I know I need to test the higher level SSN against looping through the dependents, but like  I said "I'm against my wall" :)

Data is here:

```
<ab:Report_Entry>
<ab:SSN>888881006</ab:SSN>
<ab:Last_Name>Smith</ab:Last_Name>
<ab:First_Name>Kimberly</ab:First_Name>
<ab:dependents>
<ab:Dependent_SSN>888881009</ab:Dependent_SSN>
<ab:Relation ab:Descriptor="Spouse">
</ab:Relation>
</ab:dependents>
<ab:dependents>
<ab:Dependent_SSN>888881004</ab:Dependent_SSN>
<ab:Relation ab:Descriptor="Child">
</ab:Relation>
</ab:dependents>
<ab:dependents>
<ab:Dependent_SSN>888881003</ab:Dependent_SSN>
<ab:Relation ab:Descriptor="Child">
<ab:ID ab:type="Related_Person_Relationship_ID">Child</ab:ID>
</ab:Relation>
</ab:dependents>
<ab:dependents>
<ab:Dependent_SSN>888881001</ab:Dependent_SSN>
<ab:Dependent_ID>1032D-4</ab:Dependent_ID>
<ab:Relation ab:Descriptor="Child">
<ab:ID ab:type="Related_Person_Relationship_ID">Child</ab:ID>
</ab:Relation>
</ab:dependents>
</ab:Report_Entry>
```

Thank you to any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define the type of the input parameter and the type of the function result and then you should write a function body returning a value of that type. Currently your description sounds rather procedural, that is not going to work with XSLT/XPath.

As for the error, I think in the path `/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]ab:dependents/ab:Dependent_SSN` you need one more slash `/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:dependents/ab:Dependent_SSN` to have a syntactically correct path. That should avoid the syntax error you get but is not likely to return the result you want.

Comment: Martin,  Thank you.  I'm certain how to approach the typing of the input function, but I can research that one.  
I tried your suggestion, but received the following error:

     **Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5
     Severity: fatal
     Description: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the      tree containing the context item: the context item is undefined**

Comment: The path itself is no longer an error but as you are trying to use it inside of a function it causes the error you now see. You will have to pass in a node as a parameter to your function and write a path relative to that node e.g. `<xsl:function name="ab:PQB"><xsl:param name="input" as="node()"/></xsl:param name="EE_SSN" as="xs:string"/><xsl:sequence select="$input/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:Report_Data/ab:Report_Entry[ab:Employee_ID=$EE_SSN]/ab:dependents/ab:Dependent_SSN"/></xsl:function>`. Again this is a conceptual fix, not an attempt to fix the function.